# where can I find video4linux2 device /dev/video in ubuntu 9.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu-9.04, v4l

where can I find video4linux2 device /dev/video in ubuntu 9.04.

ADDED.

I want to work with Hardware Overlays. I want to make a video player which play video on one overlay and draw controls on other overlay. For that I want to use video4linux.

Comment: You, probably want `ffplay` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to load a driver (webcam driver for example) which will create /dev/video interface.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to play with hardware overlay. I don't want to capture video. Please see Added part of Question.

Comment: Doesn't matter what you want to do, only a driver can create the /dev/video interface (You can create it by hand but that won't be useful). Check driver documentation for your gadget/hardware.